# sudo bashfile makes syntax error

Tags: bash, cron, sudo, du

i have got a bash file which i want to toggle via the sudo crontab list. Problem is, that it does not work, because when i run the script with sudo, there is a syntax error message on this line:

```
size=(`du -h $backupDir --summarize`)
```

If i run the same script without, i have to type the sudo pw, but it works without any problems.
I allready tried a few variations with brackets, with or without backticks, with or without spaces, etc but nothing helped. The error message is:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting ";;")
```

Any help?

Comment: does the script have a bash shebang ? `#!/usr/bin/env bash` or at least `#!/bin/bash` ? `(` is valid in bash, and should create an array from the command's output.

Comment: also it seems like you're not closing a `case` statement correctly, thus `expecting ;;`. posting your script would help.

Comment: the #!/bin/bash was the problem ;) All case Statements where closed correctly :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that you use bash-syntax, and the script (when it is executed from cron) is interpreted by `/bin/sh` (that known nothing about arrays and the `()` construction.).

You must either specify `bash` as an interpreter of the script using she-bang notation:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or run the script explicitly with `bash` from cron:

```
bash /path/to/script
```

or rewrite script so, that it could run without arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Fro readability use the `$()` form

```
size=$(du -h $backupDir --summarize)
```

If you want to stick to back quotes, then

```
size=`du -h $backupDir --summarize`
```

Comment: you better quote both of those. `size="\`cmd --args\`";` `size="$(cmd --args)"`

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter - While that doesn't hurt, it is not needed on the right side of a variable assignment.